# Can you create 2 rows in Excel with one Google Forms submission?

Tags: forms, google-workspace

Each Google Forms submission creates a Row in the Excel document. Is it possible to submit a single response that populates in multiple rows as opposed to columns? I.e. keeping other inputs constant but having multiple answers for one value.